# Проблема при скачивании пакета с Nuget.org для проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: c#

При попытке подключить дополнительный пакет с Nuget.org постоянно вылетает ошибка. Пробовал скачать несколько разных пакетов вылетает ошибка.
Пример ошибки следующий:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package Telegram.Bot.4.0.0.27039' with respect to project 'Telegram Bot', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Telegram.Bot.4.0.0.27039' from source 'nuget.org'.
```

Не подскажете, что это значит, и что с этим делать?

Comment: Подскажите, какой версией Visual Studio пользуетесь?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Express

Comment: попробуйте скачать пакет вручную. как это сделать - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475907/)

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему сам, следующим образом. Проблема заключалась в том что nuget.org не давал достаточную скорость для скачивания пакетов, в результате чего постоянно связь обрывалась. Скачал программу VPN клиент которая меняет IP и все сработало.