# Как скачать пакет с nuget.org и извлечь из него сборки?

Tags: .net, nuget

В ответах и документации часто вижу следующее:

- *подключите к проекту пакет ...*
- *скачайте пакет ...*
- *Install-Package ...*

Моя IDE не поддерживает работу с nuget.org.
Как скачать пакет вручную и как извлечь из него сборки?

Answer (score 8):

Например, требуется пакет [Newtonsoft.Json (версия 7.0.1)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.1).
Чтобы скачать его с nuget.org, надо перейти по ссылке

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.1

Полученный файл `newtonsoft.json.7.0.1.nupkg` - это zip-архив. Например, в Windows Explorer его можно переименовать, заменить .nupkg на .zip, и открыть.
В \lib находятся \net20, \net35, и т.д.
Если для вашего проекта требуется сборка для .NET 4.5, то в \net45 находится соответствующий файл Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: За этот ответ дали 007, верно? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin _"За этот ответ дали 007, верно?"_ -- я не помню. если где-то можно посмотреть, скажите, я посмотрю и отвечу. а на странице шляп написано что она "секретная")

Comment: хитрость в том, что на секретных шляпах не написано, за что они даны. Однако этот вопрос в точности подходит под условие. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2102/181472

Answer (score 6):

Официальный метод, судя по всему, такой:

1. Если ещё нет в системе, скачать https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe и поместить где угодно (лучше в `%PATH%`).
2. Им можно пользоваться. Например:

   > D:\Test\NugetTest\3rdparty>..\nuget.exe install rx-main
   >   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Interfaces (= 2.2.5)'.
   >   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Core (= 2.2.5)'.
   >   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Linq (= 2.2.5)'.
   >   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-PlatformServices (= 2.2.5)'.
   >   Installing 'Rx-Interfaces 2.2.5'.
   >   Successfully installed 'Rx-Interfaces 2.2.5'.
   >   Installing 'Rx-Core 2.2.5'.
   >   Successfully installed 'Rx-Core 2.2.5'.
   >   Installing 'Rx-Linq 2.2.5'.
   >   Successfully installed 'Rx-Linq 2.2.5'.
   >   Installing 'Rx-PlatformServices 2.2.5'.
   >   Successfully installed 'Rx-PlatformServices 2.2.5'.
   >   Installing 'Rx-Main 2.2.5'.
   >   Successfully installed 'Rx-Main 2.2.5'.
3. При таком методе у вас появятся к каталоге 3rdparty подкаталоги, соответствующие инсталлированным пакетам. Добавить их в ваш проект вам придётся самостоятельно: nuget не знает из коробки, как добавиться в вашу структуру проекта.

Литература:

1. [Nuget command line reference](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference)
2. [Installing NuGet packages directly from the command line](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/installing-nuget-packages-directly-from.html)