# Sql запросы в Visual Studio для SQLite (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqlite3

Нужно иметь возможность писать запросы на Sql языке в VS для SQLite, но найденные способы не помогают. Один из них -

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
```

Visual studio ругается на SQLiteCommand, который идет после 'new'. Сообщение: '"SQLiteCommand" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 2'. Не могу понять в чем ошибка, учитывая что такой синтаксис в большом кол-ве источников.

PS: использую Visual Studio 2015, SQLite.Net-PCL.

Comment: Какой тип у переменной m_dbConnection? Вероятно в ней проблема. Должен быть `SQLiteConnection`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В проект добавьте nuget-пакет [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite).
А в код добавьте `using System.Data.SQLite;`

Если в Visual Studio не установлен Package Manager Console, то nuget-пакет можно скачать вручную. Как это сделать - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475908/196972).

UPDATE:

Для Windows 10
- [SQLite for Universal App Platform](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4913e7d5-96c9-4dde-a1a1-69820d615936)
- [Implement SQLite Local Storage Using Windows 10 UWP Apps](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Implement-SQLite-Local-8b13a307).
- [Local Data Base SQLite for Windows 10](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Local-Data-Base-SQLite-for-5e6146aa#content)

Comment: Странное дело. Установил System.Data.SQLite V1.0.99, но при добавлении 'using System.Data.SQLite;' пишет ошибку об отсутствии SQLite в System.Data. Ссылку точно добавил. В подсказках при вводе только предлагает к  System.Data.дописать .Common

Comment: в Visual Studio - Solution Explorer - ... - References должна быть видна сборка SQLite. если ее нет, то надо подключить.

Comment: Он там есть. Создан универсальный проект Windows 10. Может быть в этом дело?

Comment: для Windows 10 добавил в ответ.

Comment: Сделал все что было описано на той странице.
1) SQLite for Universal App Platform Установлен;
2) Ссылка для SQLite UAP создана;
3) SQLite.Net-PCL в NuGet и так подключен вместе с сылкой;
В результате весь код у меня работает кроме той злосчастной строки с SQL запросом. Т.е. та же проблема что я описал в самом вопросе. Ругается на то же '"SQLiteCommand" во второй части строки. Может для этого расширения другой синтаксис? По указанным ссылкам на этот счет ни слова.

Comment: вместо SQLiteCommand попробуйте Query. пример - [тут](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Local-Data-Base-SQLite-for-5e6146aa#content).

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло через Query по указанной ссылке. Только появилась небольшая проблемка. При изменении поля через sql запрос, русские буквы записываются в итоге в бд ромбиками с вопросиками. Если пишу новую строку встроенной функцией SQLite.Net-PCL, все нормально. Кодировка в VS выбрана UTF-8.

Comment: @ВладиславКлимов _"При изменении поля через sql запрос, русские буквы записываются в итоге в бд ромбиками"_ -- попробуйте в бд указать кодировку. где-то в бд должны быть параметры. например, в sql server есть [collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144260(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Кодировка sqlite при создании только можно указать. По умолчанию UTF8. Я таблицей ранее в связке с питоном использовал и уверен в ее кодировке. 
UPDATE: Прикол в том, что через  var sql = connect.Insert(new table(){} Он прекрасно добавляет русский текст без знаков "?"

Comment: а какое значение в System.Text.Encoding.Default? если например SBCSCodePageEncoding { BodyName="koi8-r", CodePage=1251 }, а надо UTF8, то надо конвертировать строку из одной кодировки в другую.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33312/discussion-between---and-stack).