# Использование SHGetFileInfo

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

Использую функцию Winapi SHGetFileInfo для того чтобы достать иконку с файла и добавить ее в listView. Когда пытаюсь получить иконку с картинки, то получаю вот такой результат.

```
private  void FindFile(string path, string mask)
{
    foreach (var f in EnumerateFiles(new DirectoryInfo(path), mask))
    {
        try
        {
            Win32.SHFILEINFO sh = new Win32.SHFILEINFO();
            Win32.SHGetFileInfo(f.FullName, 0, ref sh, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(sh),
            Win32.SHGFI_ICON | Win32.SHGFI_LARGEICON | Win32.SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME);
            Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(sh.hIcon);
            imageList.Images.Add(icon);

            var lvItem = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(f.FullName), imageList.Images.Count - 1);
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(f.FullName));
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(f.FullName);
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(fileInfo.Length + " байт");
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(Directory.GetLastWriteTime(f.FullName).ToString());


            uiContext.Send(d => listView1.Items.Add(lvItem), null);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

[image: Результат]

А хотелось бы получить иконку которая реально отображается в проводнике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо получить иконку, ассоциированную с файлом, то можно использовать `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`.

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "System.Drawing"

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

var i = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\Temp\1.png").ToBitmap();
i.MakeTransparent();
var f = new Form() { Width = 500 };
var l = new ListView() {
    Parent = f,
    Dock = DockStyle.Right,
    LargeImageList = new ImageList()
};
l.LargeImageList.Images.Add(i);
l.Items.Add("C:", 0);
f.ShowDialog();
```

---

Чтобы получить иконку папки надо использовать Win API функцию `SHGetFileInfo`.
Пример на с# есть на сайте [support.microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319350).

Answer (score 2):

Вместо SHGetFileInfo можно использовать nuget-пакет Microsoft [WindowsAPICodePack.Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell/), который позволяет получать иконки разных рамеров.

К проекту надо подключить следующие сборки

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll"
#r "System.Drawing"
```

---

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack;
using System.Windows.Forms;

var sf = ShellFolder.FromParsingName(@"c:\") as ShellFolder;
var f = new Form() { Width = 500 };
var i = sf.Thumbnail.Bitmap;
i.MakeTransparent();
var p = new PictureBox() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Image = i };
var l = new ListView() { Parent = f, 
                         Dock = DockStyle.Right, 
                         LargeImageList = new ImageList() };
l.LargeImageList.Images.Add(i);
l.Items.Add("C:", 0);
f.ShowDialog();
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Способ конечно интересный, но мне желательно решить эту проблему средствами winapi или .net, без использования сторонних сборок.

Comment: @Lightness _"мне желательно решить эту проблему средствами winapi или .net, без использования сторонних сборок"_ -- если так, то можно заглянуть reflector'ом или ilspy'ем в  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll и посмотреть как и что сделано и применить у себя. как скачать вручную пакет и достать сборку - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475907/).

Comment: Скачал, ILspy`ем открыл, но как-то довольно сложно понять как это сделано. Буду пытаться.

Comment: @Lightness _"довольно сложно понять как это сделано"_ -- в ilspy не знаю как, но в reflector есть поиск по функциям/методам и надо искать SHGetFileInfo.   я добавил еще один ответ. внизу есть ссылка на пример вызова SHGetFileInfo на c# .

Comment: @Stack, не проще ли смотреть не реплектором/ilspy, а просто в исходники проекта на GitHub'е? Там всё таки комментарии, структура проекта нормальная, куски кода ещё не заинлайнены компилятором..

Comment: @SergeyRufanov _"не проще ли смотреть не реплектором/ilspy, а просто в исходники проекта на GitHub'е"_ -- не у всех сборок, исходник выложен на github. и на github - это просто файлы, а в reflector'е есть навигация по типам, методам, также как на http://referencesource.microsoft.com/